# Does CS4 support softkeyboard for desktop applications

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, android-softkeyboard, cs4

I need to use softkeyboard for a flash program developed for windows desktop, and I tried the example given on the following page:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f6bc38fcc12e0166e73b-7fff.html

When I test the movie, it gives me a compiler error:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property needsSoftKeyboard through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

I noticed that this feature is available to flash players 10.2 or higher, so I updated my CS4, but it still didn't work. Does anybody know what is causing the problem?

Many thanks.